# A more Pythonic Way to clean up strings

Tags: python, string, replace

I am looking to clean up some strings to make them column names and the easiest method i found is a series of replace statements: is there a cleaner way to achieve this outcome?

Sample String for clarity:

```
0                                 Estimate!!Total:
1                          Estimate!!Total:!!Male:
2           Estimate!!Total:!!Male:!!Under 5 years
3            Estimate!!Total:!!Male:!!5 to 9 years
```

Outcome:

```
0                  Total:
1                   Male:
2            Male_Under_5
3             Male_5_to_9
4           Male_10_to_14
5           Male_15_to_17
```

Code:

```
test['LABEL'].str.replace("Estimate!!Total:!!", "").str.replace("Estimate!!", "")\
.str.replace(':!!','_').str.replace('years','').str.replace('years','').str.replace(' ','_').str.rstrip('_')
```

Comment: "Cleaner" and "more Pythonic" are subjective. However, you could try putting the replacing targets and replacements as a dict and looping through. I am also unsure why you replaced `years` with nothing twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try putting the replacements in a dict, like so:

```py
replacements = {
    "Estimate!!Total:!!": "",
    "Estimate!!": "",
    ":!!": "_",
    "years": "",
    " ": "_"
}
```

Then to actually replace:

```py
for target, replacement in replacements.items():
    test['LABEL'] = test['LABEL'].str.replace(target, replacement)

test['LABEL'].str = test['LABEL'].str.rstrip('_')
```

Note that is operation is in-place (e. g. will modify the original value.)

Also note that using `test['LABEL'].str` may be considered bad practice as there is already a builtin class called `str`. Maybe try modifying how `test['LABEL']` is created so that `.str` is called something like `.string` instead?

Or if there is no other information in `test['LABEL']` besides the string, you could just get rid of the `.str` and adjust `test['LABEL']` to be just the string.

Comment: Keep in mind that `str.replace` is _greedy_ and works always from left to right

Answer (score 2):

You can try an approach similar to `split` & `join` wrt a *delimiter*. Here it's assumed the `!!` is the fixed delimiter. Use `str` methods such as `endswith` and `removesuffix` to make it more Pythonic (check `help(str)` for details).

Using *walrus* operator, Python >= 3.8

```
text = # string of text

padding = 10 # amount of white spaces

apply_line_template = f"{{:<{padding}}}{{}}".format
for i, line in enumerate(text.splitlines(), 0):
    print(
        apply_line_template(
            i, 
            (
                'Male_' + '_'.join(t.removesuffix('years').split())
                if (t := line.rpartition('!!')[-1]).endswith('years')
                else t
            )
        )
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are dealing with string alone and not some dataframe then you can use `str.rsplit` method as

```
>>> string = 'stimate!!Total:!!Male:!!5 to 9 years'
>>> string_new = string.rsplit('!!', 1)[-1]
>>> string_new
'5 to 9 years'
```

this goes for all other one, as there is pattern in each string having `!!` dividing factor.